# Automate & Export Google Sheet to Excel

Tags: javascript

I would like to export a google sheet as an excel file and store it on a local folder. THis needs to be triggered daily with a scheduler

Comment: You can download it from google drive. It will be automatically converting to excel format.

Comment: What does your attempt look like?

Comment: I would like to automate the export, so my application can fetch data from it. Currently the app is not able to load data from a web file like google sheet, which is why i need to take this approach